# How to skip the last records using sql-loader?

Tags: oracle, plsql

We are using flat files.but how to skip the last records in flat files.

Comment: What does the Tail Record start with? will it always be the same? be more clear. If the Tail Record Starts with a T use the following answer i provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Following in your ctl File if your tail record always starts with T! Haven't tested it in a while but worked for me the last time i worked with loading a staging table.

```
    LOAD DATA
    INFILE 'file.dat' BADFILE 'file.bad' DISCARDFILE 'file.dis'
    APPEND
    INTO TABLE tablename
-- This will skip the tail record
    WHEN (01) <> 'T'
    (
    column names);
```

Comment: But iam gettint below error.                                                                 load data
infile 'C:\Users\Ranga\Desktop\sqll\book1.csv'
insert
into table test
fields terminated by ','
trailing nullcols
when(01)!='T'
(empno, ename, sal)                                                                                  error                                                                                     SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 7.
Expecting "(", found keyword when.
when(01)!='T'

Comment: This clause is working.But not skip the last two records.please give sample example code?

Comment: I thought you wanted to skip the last record? how many records from the tail do you have to skip?

Comment: But using When causes rejections and create a bad file. Is there any way to skip record not reject it so I should not get a bad file due to this as it happens in case of SKIP clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the header rows using the SKIP clause but to skip the last records you will have to use the WHEN clause. Typically, your trailing records (last records) will not be identical to the other records in the file and there should be an indicator to specify that this is a trailer record. You need to construct such a condition in your control file that this condition does not get satisfied.

Here is the Oracle documentation on the WHEN clause.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10825/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005657

Here are some examples on conditional loading.

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader#Conditional_Load

Answer (score 0):

Your original post needs more detail but for completeness the control file options clause has a LOAD = n option that tells sqlldr how many rows to load.  If you have 100 rows and don't want to load the last 5, specify LOAD = 95.

Comment: If one does not know total no of records coming file then ?

Comment: @MSingh You'd need a wrapper program that counts lines in the file, does the calculation then calls the sqlldr command line with the appropriate value for LOAD=